# Error 1001 when installing a windows service

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

i am getting an error 1001 when installing windows service using installshield.
the following error was generated and saved in the event management logs. The installer worked fine until it was updated with a few dlls. Any possible resolution. the installer logs reveal nothing more in detail

> The description for Event ID 11001 from source MsiInstaller cannot be
>   found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on
>   your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install
>   or repair the component on the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information
>   had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:
>
> Product: ************ -- Error 1001.  (NULL) (NULL) (NULL) (NULL)
>   (NULL)
>
> the message resource is present but the message is not found in the
>   string/message table

Comment: 1001 means "recursion too deep; the stack overflowed".  No idea what that means in terms of InstallShield.

Comment: Most likely you are using Installer classes to install your service. This is unnecessary - if you have a version of InstallShield that supports native install of services using MSIs ServiceInstall and ServiceControl tables then use them instead. That error message is just the undocumented error when there is a failure in the InstallUtilLib mechanism that locates and runs your installer class methods.

Comment: This is an issue with .net framework 4.6 and installshield 2014/2015. There is a service pack that might fix this issue.